# Ruby watir, I want to validate currency formatting in watir, what is the best way to do it

Tags: ruby, regex, watir-webdriver

The amount can be $0.00, $100.00, $34,346,456.00 or anything like that, all I am sure about is $ and . will always be there and value will be upto 2 decimal places.

Comment: Wouldn't you just validate the exact text? For example, you would do the data setup to create an amount of "$34,346,456.00" and then check that exact text appears?

Comment: No,I can't do that,  because the value is bound to change each day with market going up or down,  I am automating webtrading application.

Comment: You could do anything from using an existing ruby gem (e.g. money) to using a brute-force regex (e.g. `\A.*\d{2}\z`).  FWIW: you'll get better answers if you include the properly-formatted code that you've written to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The text of an element is a string object, that means you can use the `.match` method to see if it matches a regular expression.  If you don't know about regular expressions now is the time to learn.  bingle "ruby regular expression tutorial"

you can also benefit immensely by using a tool to test your regex and see that it is matching or not matching as you expect it to.  My favorite site for that is http://rubular.com/